# Wordpress wp-ecommerce, Test Gateway, send email to admin too

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, email

My client doesn't want to accept online payments, just have the order details emailed, so I'm using the Test Gateway. It's only sending emails to the buyer and I need it to send to the admin's email too.

Here's the code from the plugin:

```
$email = wpsc_get_buyers_email($purchase_log['id']);
```

I tried making it an array, but it throws errors and doesn't work. I don't have a lot of php experience!

```
$email = array (wpsc_get_buyers_email($purchase_log['id']), 'myemail@email.com');
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the wp-ecomemrce plugin then you shouldn't have to edit any code the admin email address will get sent emails of new orders. Have a look through the backend settings in wordpress you may have flicked a setting off.

Comment: you were right! Silly mistake, I overlooked part of the Store's Admin section, thinking it was about downloads. Silly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was just searching for the same, but couldn't find an easy answer anywhere. I know the topic is quite old but this solution should be quite helpful.

In my WP-Ecommerce I edited:

`wpsc-theme/functions/wpsc-transaction_results_functions.php`

I just added merchant `idealcheckoutideal` (this could be any merchant) and the functions that fire the notification emails. I guess you could call those functions anywhere as long as you are using the `purchase_log` parameter.

```
if ( $selected_gateway ) {
        switch( $selected_gateway ){
            case 'anymerchant you want':

                if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['sessionid'] ) )
                      return;


                $purchase_log = new WPSC_Purchase_Log( $_REQUEST['sessionid'], 'sessionid' );
                wpsc_send_admin_email($purchase_log); 
                wpsc_send_customer_email($purchase_log);               

            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

How is it sending the mail? Is it using php's `mail()` or `wp_mail()`. If it's using php's `mail()` you should send the `$email` variable as comma separated, not as an array. (If it's their custom roller, also try sending the addresses separated by a comma)

Comment: I tried comma separated, minus the array tag like this: $email = wpsc_get_buyers_email($purchase_log['id']), 'sarah@amperandsand.com';       The code that sends the email is (I think):  if ( ! get_transient( "{$sessionid}_pending_email_sent" ) ) {
      wp_mail( $email, __( 'Order Pending: Angela Fashion', 'wpsc' ), $message );
      set_transient( "{$sessionid}_pending_email_sent", true, 60 * 60 * 12 );
     }

Comment: -   This gives me the error and breaks the site: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /homepages/16/d392665558/htdocs/testing/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-theme/functions/wpsc-transaction_results_functions.php on line 144